# Angular 2 - How does one make the paths relative to the root of the project?

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, razor, path

I have the following systemjs.config.js file located in a Visual Studio MVC project in the Scripts folder. The path would be root/Scripts/systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'libs/'
      },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: '/Scripts/app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      '.': {
          defaultJSExtensions: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

All my javascript files for angular are in Scripts/app and all the modules are located in libs.

In my production enviroment my website URL is www.mywebsite.com/user/firstpage while locally when developing the website is www.mywebsite.com/firstpage.

I load the angular app in the master layout of the page using

```
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->

    <script src="~/libs/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app/main")').catch(function (err)
        {
            console.error(err);
        });
    </script>
```

On the home page locally I am fine and angular loads. On the home page in production I get an error that it can't find main.

```
www.mywebsite.com/user/Scripts/app/main 404 (Not Found)
```

If I play with the urls a bit I can get the main.js file to load but when the libs files are not working as they are looking from mywebsite.com in production instead of mywebsite.com/user. So in production they are showing 404 as mywebsite.com/libs/component instead of mywebsite.com/user/libs/component.

How can I get the paths to also go from the root of my website in production and local?

Comment: do you have a <base href='Scripts' /> tag on your hosting HTML page?

Comment: No, I'm not aware of what that is. How do I use that?

Comment: All relative URLs use the <base> tag to figure out the location - just have to set it correctly: https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_base.asp

Comment: @pixelbits That did the trick! I ended up using <base href="~/">. Make an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `<base href="..." >` tag. Specify a default URL and a default target for all relative links on a page.

https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_base.asp